# How can use wxPython on Ubuntu 23?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, wxpython

I'm trying to use wxPython on a project in Python3 in a computer Ubuntu 23 based. When I try to import wxPython to my project this error appears me:

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython
Running setup.py clean for wxPython
Failed to build wxPython

What can I do? Do you recomend me to use another binding to solve this problem with this properties?

Thank you so much!